# Rspec tests, difference between should vs expect

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am testing my models.

I have the following test:

```
it "....." do
  perm = FactoryGirl.create(:permission)
  new_permission = perm.dup

  new_permission.valid?.should be_false
end
```

This test passes. But if I change it to:

```
expect { new_permission.valid? }.to be_false
```

Why?

I get the following error:

```
     Failure/Error: expect{new_permission.valid?}.to be_false
   expected: false value
        got: #<Proc:0x007f9d20298258@/Users/..../Desktop/Projects/.../spec/models/permission_spec.rb:16>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: but have you tried? `expect { new_permission.valid? }.to be_false` to `expect(new_permission.valid?).to be_false` ?

Comment: block can be used for `Expecting errors` `Yielding` and `Expecting throws`

Comment: @Monk_Code Make it an answer!

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thanks i was not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
expect { new_permission.valid? }.to be_false
```

use

```
expect(new_permission.valid?).to be_false
```

the block form can used for Expecting and Yielding. You can read more about [the difference between `should` and `expect` in the docs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

Monk, can you explain me a bit this sentence : block can used for Expecting and Yielding ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Tony See the docs for [`raise_error` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) & [yield matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/yield-matchers).

Comment: `expect(new_permission).to_not be_valid`  Would be an even better way to write that spec. @Tony